# Emacs: как устанавливать пакеты?

Tags: emacs

Хочу попробовать emacs, но без встроенного файлового браузера, по-моему, вообще невозможно работать (dired - подходит, когда работаешь с двумя, тремя файлами, но когда работаешь с десятком, по-моему, это нереально).  
Хочу установить Emacs-nav и не врублюсь, как это сделать. В list-packeges его нет. Делаю по такому [туториалу](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs-nav). Там сказано ввести определенный код в `~/.emacs`. У меня вообще нет такого пути, есть  `~/.emacs.d`. Захожу и не знаю, куда надо ввести код, который в туториале, у меня там только файлы `auto-save-list`, `elpa`, `eshell`. Куда вводить-то? 
Еще надо скачать там архив. Я его скачала и не знаю, куда его девать. Вообще непонятно. 
Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Сделал. Если интересно, то это мой многострадальный рабочий .emacs

http://pastebin.com/1HtxdRxS

Comment: @avp, что у вас написано (в конфиге комментом выше) в первых трех строках (закомментированных)? Латиница вперемешку с кириллицей или какие то экзотические символы? У меня, что то, браузер квадраты показывает

Comment: Да, там какая-то ерунда типа "это русские буковки" в разных кодировках, которая потом пострадала еще и от дополнительных перекодировок. Не ломайте голову

Comment: @avp, спасибо. А то 4 года потратил на исследование и ничего не понял)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так создайте этот файл с указанным содержимым.

```
cat >> ~/.emacs
```

paste emacs-lisp code  from URL

```
^D
```

Потом все настройки emacs-а будете добавлять туда.

А вообще-то я, например, использую emacs параллельно с Thunar (файл-манагер в xubuntu) или Nautilus в ubuntu или каким-нибудь другим GNOME-файл-манагером в др. Linux-ах.

Для открытия файла мне `Ctrl-x Ctrl-f` + `<Tab>` (дополняет имена файлов) вполне хватает.

Опять же из командной строки всегда можно любую *nix-команду выполнить (`Meta-!`).

И для начала, запустите emacs, наберите `Ctrl-h t` и читайте туториал.

Answer (score 1):

**dired** прикольная штуковина, если почитать про все ее возможности.

Если нужно отрыть файл, то ничего делать грандиозного не надо:

```
C-x C-f
```

Много файлов:

```
C-x C-f ~/foo/*.c RET
```

Если нужно визауальное решение гляньте тут

- https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree
- https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Sunrise_Commander

Не настроенным Emacs пользоватся конечно можно, но есть куча уже подогнанных и отлаженных сборок:

- http://spacemacs.org/
- https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d

Если отвечать на вопрос, заданный в названии темы:

M-x package-list-packages

Answer (score 1):

Если только начинаете - используйте менеджер пакетов, например MELPA. Там около 4200 разных пакетов. Описание установки тут:
http://melpa.org/#/getting-started
По сути, если вы еще в самом-самом начале настройки, достаточно удалить/перенести старый файл .emacs и создать новый со следующим содержимым:

```
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  (when no-ssl
    (warn "\
Your version of Emacs does not support SSL connections,
which is unsafe because it allows man-in-the-middle attacks.
There are two things you can do about this warning:
1. Install an Emacs version that does support SSL and be safe.
2. Remove this warning from your init file so you won't see it again."))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
    (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "gnu" (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)
```

После этого перезапустите emacs

А перечень пакетов тут:
http://melpa.org/#/
Далее всё просто. Нажимаете M-x (Alt+X в emacs терминологии) и вводите команду:

```
package-list-packages
```

После чего получите список все доступных пакетов от встроенных (GNU), до тех что установили (melpa). Подводите курсор к нужному, нажимаете Enter, открывается дополнительное окно где нажав на ссылку Install можно установить любой.
Читайте описание к каждому пакету. Какие-то пакеты сразу вписываются и запускаются как влитые, какие-то для запуска нужно прописывать в .emacs, ну или запускать внутренней командой. Думаю, что разберётесь, так как всё, как правило, очень хорошо обписано. Особыне знания lisp в этом плане не особо требуется и устанавливается всё довольно легко и без ошибок.

Описание как подключить пакетный менеджер

Список пакетов для emacs